# Does will affect your psi soldiers' attacks in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

In *XCOM: Enemy Unknown/Within*, the success of your psi soldiers psi attacks depended in part on how high their will stat was.

In the new XCOM 2, the will stat increases your soldiers' resistance to psi attacks, just like it did in the previous game.

However, there is now a new "psi" stat on psi soldiers, in addition to the will stat. Does "will" still influence the effectiveness of your psi attacks, or does it only determine psi defense, while the new psi stat alone improves psi attacks?

Answer (score 7):

According to [XCOM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Psi_Operative_(XCOM_2)):

> The success of psi attacks is only affected by the operative's Psi stat - which is increased by using upgraded Psi Amps - and not Will. Will is only a factor when defending against psi attacks, and improving Will (such as through a Personal Combat Sim) will not increase the operative's Psi rating. In short: Psi = Offense, Will = Defense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Offense is only affected by Psi anymore. I have a Psi op with 133 will, and 139 Psi, pretty decent Psi Op. But she can't Dominate Gatekeepers or Codexes with 100% success.

My last playthrough, I was able to dominate anything with 100% success. Except maybe codexes were about 95-99%.

Now they're like 75%.

And every time I've tried, I get a -100% reduction due to Will.

W\So if Will doesn't affect offensive attacks, why is it affecting my dominate ability?

Comment: Gatekeepers, being psionic in nature, were always on the low side with domination. I have never been able to control gatekeepers with 100% accuracy, and I have played with a full psionic squad before. The -100% reduction due to Will is the enemy will stat resisting you controlling the unit. (Source that supports that Gatekeepers had a 70-ish percent chance to be controlled. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/254796/68284 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when using a targeted skill like stasis you can use the small arrows by the hit percentage to popout more details, this will show all the boosts and drains to the hit%. IIR will is directly used as the base hit% and has the enemies will subtracted from it.

I believe the aliens get the same formula this could be check by mind-controlling a sectiod while one of your agents has been controled.

**Edit.**

@ChrisHayes and @DarthPizza have corrected my bad memory in that psi attacks use the 'Psi Offense' stat to hit and 'Will' to defend. I'll have to check if any of my high will agents have an increased psi attack stat but I don't think they will

Comment: This is incorrect; your chance to hit comes only from Psi Offense, which is not based on will. Will only factors in when defending against psi attacks.

Comment: I read the description for the "Domination" ability, under Soldier Abilities (if you click on the yellow question mark icon on the ability), and it says that it compares the soldier's Psi strength vs the target's will, so it appears that @ChrisHayes is correct.

Comment: Ok cool, I couldn't check atm - I'll update the answer

Comment: Also, Stasis doesn't have a % chance to work in the first place -- it just always works.