# Are Gatekeepers vulnerable to EMP Bombs?

Tags: xcom-2

Can I use an EMP Bomb on the Gatekeepers?  For that matter are they treated as Robotic or Organic when considering vulnerability to specialty grenade attacks?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are treated as Robotic, and as such, they are vulnerable to EMPs and other items with bonus Mechanical damage.

Comment: You can't actually *hack* a Gatekeeper though, can you?

Comment: @Studoku I actually just tried this as well, and I can confirm that an EMP Bomb does indeed heavily damage a Gatekeeper, and can even stun it for 2 turns!

Comment: @peper757 I've already tried it, you can't hack them. I guess it works something like Andromedon pilots, you can't hack their suit until you kill the organic pilot first. In the case of the Andromedon, killing the pilot just results in a massive explosion.

Comment: As a bonus, if you hit them with an EMP grenade after they've summoned Psi Zombies, all their minions will die instantly as the Gatekeeper is shut down for two turns.