# What types of enemies are vulnerable to EMP Grenades and Bombs?

Tags: xcom-2

"Robotic" enemies are supposed to be vulnerable to EMPs, but it's not always obvious what counts as a robotic enemy, as demonstrated by [Are Gatekeepers vulnerable to EMP Bombs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255334/90128).

For example, the Gatekeeper can be mind controlled, so it's "organic", but it's also vulnerable to EMPs, I suppose because of its robotic shell.

So which types of enemies can actually take damage, or be disabled in someway, by EMP weapons?

Answer (score 6):

The following types of enemies are vulnerable to EMPs:

1. Turrets (take damage, not sure if can be shutdown or suffer lowered hacking defense).
2. MECs (take damage, chance to be shutdown for 2 turns, and suffer lowered hacking defense).
3. Sectopods (take damage, chance to be shutdown for 2 turns, and suffer lowered hacking defense).
4. Gatekeepers (take damage, and chance to be stunned for 2 turns).
5. Codexes (take damage, not sure if any other effects).
6. Andromedon suits with dead pilots (take damage, not sure if can be shutdown or suffer lowered hacking defense).
7. Shieldbearers (take no damage, but instantly removes shields).

I confirmed that Andromedon suits don't take EMP damage while their pilots are still alive.

Comment: Andromaedons seem to behave like organics when the pilot is alive and as mech when they aren't.

Comment: I am pretty sure that "stunned" is the same as "shutdown". E.g., Arc Blade will "Shut Down" mechanicals, despite only listing a "Stun" chance.